# Can i use BeforeEach and afterEach functions in config file in protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node, karma-mocha

I wonder if can use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` functions in `config` file in protractor in order to avoid repeating common code for all scripts ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, try post an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You won't be able to use it. Config file is parsed initially when the automation execution starts. If you have repetitive code then write a generic function which you can call whenever you need.

Comment: @user2677821: for eg ( aftereach function that delete cookies, close browser and delete log.

Comment: @Girish : ok so i can only write on prepare function inside config file !

Comment: I would suggest you to write in a separate .js file which you can import and call as and when required. On prepare function is executed only once too, and it's not a good practice to write your functions in it.

Comment: Ok thanks for details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. But [Protractor's config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js) does allow you to use `beforeLaunch`, `onPrepare`, and `onComplete` blocks. Those should get you where you want to be.